# Fadeout is not a function jquery 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

so i've beens using this below code for most of my web projects so far

```
 setTimeout(function() {
 jQuery('.pre_loading').fadeOut('fast');
 }, 4200); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

This function returns an uncaught type error saying "$(...).fadeOut is not a function".

when i tried switching my jquery library file to an older version 1.12 there seems to be no issue. But since i've updated my jquery file i'm seeing this issue. Any ideas?

I'm using bootstrp 4.1.3 & popper.min.js.

Comment: what is the current jquery version you are using?

Comment: If you're using slim version, that don't have all the features of the full version.

Comment: Please add your sample code in jsfiddle

Comment: hi @ui_dev i'm using jQuery v3.3.1

Comment: hey @teemu yeah you were right. i was using the slim version. Now it's working fine! thanks a ton man

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will happen if you're using the "slim" version of jQuery. Only the "full" version of jQuery includes animation effects.

Try grabbing the "full" version of jQuery from the jQuery downloads page and including that in your page (or include a full version of jQuery from a CDN from your page).